# Significance of 'localhost' in HELO localhost

Tags: smtp

In SMTP, what is supposed to come after the HELO command and what does it do?

I'm sending email in my application and I'm wondering if I should use *localhost*, the domain name of the from-address (me@*example.com*), the domain name of the application server (where the email is being sent from) or something else.

Comment: RTFM.  Current version of spec is 5321.  Read here (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.2) and here (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter after HELO should identify the system *sending* the email. So, you would use an externally addressable DNS name for your sending machine.

Do not use `localhost` because a lot of spam software does that, and your email will be marked as spam.

From [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt):

> 4.1.1.1  Extended HELLO (EHLO) or HELLO (HELO)
>
> These commands are used to identify the SMTP client to the SMTP
>      server.  The argument field contains the fully-qualified domain name
>      of the SMTP client if one is available.

I would usually recommend that you use a real MTA, and hand off your email to the MTA for ultimate delivery. That way you don't have to reinvent the implementation of the SMTP protocol, which is surprisingly easy to get wrong.

Comment: I am using the PHP PEAR Mail library - which allows you to specify the localhost parameter :) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @arex1337: I still recommend the use of a real MTA. What will happen when the remote mail server is down or unavailable--at what time will you retry sending that message? A real MTA does that for you. You can still connect to your MTA using the PEAR Mail library if you like.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the domain name of the application server.

```
  HELO <SP> <domain> <CRLF>

  In the HELO command the host sending the command identifies
  itself; the command may be interpreted as saying "Hello, I am
  <domain>".
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821